# Can I do math inside Python's string formatting "language"?

Tags: python

I would like to do some simple math while I'm doing string formatting. For example

```
N = {'number':3}
four = '{number:d + 1}'.format(**N)
```

This doesn't work (of course). Is there a way to accomplish this that I'm not aware of?

Thanks!

Comment: Um, do it outside of the string?

Comment: You can subclass `Formatter` (https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/utils/text.py#L577) if you really want to. But generally it's recommended to do maths in code, and just let the formatter do formatting.

Comment: I was trying to avoid doing anything outside of the string. I need to use the same data in two places; in one place I need to add one and another the unmodified data. This is doable, but I was hoping there would be some Python magic that would solve this. There is every other time! That's why I love Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Is there a way to accomplish this that I'm not aware of?"  If by "this" you mean encoding some mathematical logic in the format string using str.format, then no -- not that I'm aware of.  However if you use a templating language you can express all kinds of stuff like this.

There are a billion different options for templating languages in Python, so rather than try to say which is best, I'll let you decide.  See this article from the Python wiki: http://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating

A favorite of mine is [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/), although it's probably overkill for what you're talking about.

Here's an example of how to accomplish what you're after with Jinja2:

```
N = { 'd' : 3 }
four = Template(u'number:{{ d + 1 }}').render(**N)
```

The main advantage to a templating system like Jinja2 is that it allows you store templates as files separate from your application control logic such that you can maintain the view/presentation logic for your program in a way that limits or prohibits side effects from presentation execution.

Comment: If you've ever used Django before, Jinja2 will be very easy to pick up.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I figured it wasn't very likely that I could do what I wanted to do. Templating seems like it would work, but is way overkill for what I'm trying to accomplish. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

About as close as you can get is to use positional arguments instead of keyword arguments:

```
four='{0:d}'.format(N['number']+1)
```

or the shorter old-school:

```
four='%d'%(N['number']+1)
```

What's your goal here?

Comment: I thought of that, but the string has way to many options for positional arguments to work well; I'd quickly get lost.

Answer (score -1):

It is year 2023, we can consider this solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53671539/4563935

For your example, this works:

```
def fstr(template):
    return eval(f"f'{template}'")

number = 3
number_plus_one = "{number + 1}"
print(fstr(number_plus_one))
```