# How to evaluate a variable as an f-string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, string-interpolation, f-string

I would like to have a mechanism which evaluates an f-string where the contents to be evaluated are provided inside a variable.  For example,

```
x=7
s='{x+x}'
fstr_eval(s)
```

For the usage case I have in mind, the string `s` may arise from user input (where the user is trusted with `eval`).

While using `eval` in production is generally very bad practice, there are notable exceptions.  For instance, the user may be a Python developer, working on a local machine, who would like to use full Python syntax to develop SQL queries.

**Note on duplication:** There are similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42497625/10155767) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47869722/10155767).  The first question was asked in the limited context of templates.  The second question, although very similar to this one, has been marked as a duplicate.  Because the context of this question is significantly different from the first, I decided to ask this third question based on the automatically-generated advice following the second question:

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If
>   those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new
>   question.

Answer (score 8):

Even with a trusted user, using `eval` should only be a very last resort.

If you are willing to sacrifice flexibility of your syntax for a bit more security and control, then you could use `str.format` and provide it your whole scope.

This will disallow evaluation of expressions, but single variables will be formated into the output.

### Code

```
x = 3
y = 'foo'

s = input('> ')
print(s.format(**vars()))
```

### Example

```
> {x} and {y}
3 and foo
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is my attempt at more robust evaluation of f-strings, inspired by [kadee's elegant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53671539/10155767) to a similar question.

I would however like to avoid some basic pitfalls of the `eval` approach.  For instance, `eval(f"f'{template}'")` fails whenever the template contains an apostrophe, e.g. `the string's evaluation` becomes `f'the string's evaluation'` which evaluates with a syntax error.  The first improvement is to use triple-apostrophes:

```
eval(f"f'''{template}'''")
```

Now it is (mostly) safe to use apostrophes in the template, as long as they are not triple-apostrophes.  (Triple-quotes are however fine.)  A notable exception is an apostrophe at the end of the string: `whatcha doin'` becomes `f'''whatcha doin''''` which evaluates with a syntax error at the fourth consecutive apostrophe.  The following code avoids this particular issue by stripping apostrophes at the end of the string and putting them back after evaluation.

```
import builtins

def fstr_eval(_s: str, raw_string=False, eval=builtins.eval):
    r"""str: Evaluate a string as an f-string literal.

    Args:
       _s (str): The string to evaluate.
       raw_string (bool, optional): Evaluate as a raw literal 
           (don't escape \). Defaults to False.
       eval (callable, optional): Evaluation function. Defaults
           to Python's builtin eval.

    Raises:
        ValueError: Triple-apostrophes ''' are forbidden.
    """
    # Prefix all local variables with _ to reduce collisions in case
    # eval is called in the local namespace.
    _TA = "'''" # triple-apostrophes constant, for readability
    if _TA in _s:
        raise ValueError("Triple-apostrophes ''' are forbidden. " + \
                         'Consider using """ instead.')

    # Strip apostrophes from the end of _s and store them in _ra.
    # There are at most two since triple-apostrophes are forbidden.
    if _s.endswith("''"):
        _ra = "''"
        _s = _s[:-2]
    elif _s.endswith("'"):
        _ra = "'"
        _s = _s[:-1]
    else:
        _ra = ""
    # Now the last character of s (if it exists) is guaranteed
    # not to be an apostrophe.

    _prefix = 'rf' if raw_string else 'f'
    return eval(_prefix + _TA + _s + _TA) + _ra
```

Without specifying an evaluation function, this function's local variables are accessible, so

```
print(fstr_eval(r"raw_string: {raw_string}\neval: {eval}\n_s: {_s}"))
```

prints

```
raw_string: False
eval: <built-in function eval>
_s: raw_string: {raw_string}\neval: {eval}\n_s: {_s}
```

While the prefix `_` reduces the likelihood of unintentional collisions, the issue can be avoided by passing an appropriate evaluation function.  For instance, one could pass the current global namespace by means of `lambda`:

```
fstr_eval('{_s}', eval=lambda expr: eval(expr))#NameError: name '_s' is not defined
```

or more generally by passing suitable `globals` and `locals` arguments to `eval`, for instance

```
fstr_eval('{x+x}', eval=lambda expr: eval(expr, {}, {'x': 7})) # 14
```

I have also included a mechanism to select whether or not `\` should be treated as an escape character via the "raw string literal" mechanism.  For example,

```
print(fstr_eval(r'x\ny'))
```

yields

```
x
y
```

while

```
print(fstr_eval(r'x\ny', raw_string=True))
```

yields

```
x\ny
```

There are likely other pitfalls which I have not noticed, but for many purposes I think this will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

a simpler solution using eval took from https://stackoverflow.com/a/54071505

```
def effify(non_f_str: str):
    return eval(f'f"""{non_f_str}"""')

x=7
print (effify ("{x+x}"))
```

Comment: This is extremely fragile. As per my answer above, `effify('asdf"')` produces a syntax error. There's a reason my solution is so complicated. :)