# Trying to evaluate a string as an f-string results in AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'f()'

Tags: python, string, string-formatting, attributeerror, f-string

I have a string that contains `{...}` f-string elements that I'd like to get evaluated. And [How to evaluate a variable as an f-string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54700826/how-to-evaluate-a-variable-as-an-f-string) tells me to do this:

```py
>>> class A:
...     def f(self):
...             return "something"
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a.f()
'something'
>>> f"{a.f()}"
'something'
>>> "{a.f()}".format(**vars())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'f()'
```

However, I get the error above.

Comment: you missed the `f` before the string in the 2nd example ?

Comment: ah, sorry, I was too fast. Now I get your point.

Comment: You can call a method in an f-string, but not when using `str.format`.