# Is it possible to reuse an f-string as it is possible with a string and format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

I would like to create an f-string that could be used multiple times as the following code with `format`:

```
TEXT_AMOUNT = 'text {amount}'


def f1(beginning):
    return beginning + TEXT_AMOUNT.format(amount=10)


def f2(ending):
    return TEXT_AMOUNT.format(amount=100) + ending
```

How can I achieve the same functionality with using an f-string? I tried:

```
TEXT_AMOUNT = f'text {amount}'


def f1(beginning):
    amount = 100
    return beginning + TEXT_AMOUNT


def f2(ending):
    amount = 10
    return TEXT_AMOUNT + ending
```

However, I get the following error:

> ```
> NameError: name 'amount' is not defined
> ```

Comment: An f-string is executable code. Doing `TEXT_AMOUNT = f'text {amount}'` expects the global variable `amount` to be defined so that it can be substituted into the value assigned to `TEXT_AMOUNT` *when that assignment is executed.* You can't store an f-string in a variable.  In other words, for your use case, use `str.format()`.

Comment: It's worth skimming through [PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) to see the reasoning behind why f-strings were designed this way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to postpone/defer the evaluation of f-strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42497625/how-to-postpone-defer-the-evaluation-of-f-strings)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't.

An f-string isn't a kind of string, it's a kind of string literal, which is evaluated immediately. You can't store an f-string in a variable to be evaluated later, or accept one from a user, etc.<sup>1</sup> This is the only reason that they're safe.

So, what if you *do* want to use a format multiple times (or one taken from a user, etc.)? You use `str.format`.

Occasionally, you need to capture all of the locals and globals the same way an f-string does, but to do it explicitly. Because this is a rare case (and potentially a security hole), it's intentionally a bit ugly:

```
TEXT_AMOUNT = 'text {amount}'

def f1(beginning):
    amount = 100
    return beginning + TEXT_AMOUNT.format(**locals(), **globals())
```

This makes you think about what you're writing—you don't really want `globals` here, right? So leave it off. And it also signals the reader—if you're pulling in `locals`, they'll want to see that the string really is a constant in your source that isn't doing anything dangerous.

---

<sub>1. Well, you *could* use an f-string inside a string that you pass to `eval`… but that's a terrible idea.</sub>

Comment: thanks for the clarification. It seems I will continue using `format`. I hopped it was somehow possible.

Answer (score 21):

You can store it as [lambda](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp) function:

```
TEXT_AMOUNT = lambda amount: f'text {amount}'
print(TEXT_AMOUNT(10))

out: 'text 10'
```

Answer (score 10):

But you can put f-string in a function and reuse it that way

```
def TEXT_AMOUNT(amount):
    return f'text {amount}'

def f1(beginning):
    return beginning + " " + TEXT_AMOUNT(amount=10)

def f2(ending):
    return TEXT_AMOUNT(amount=100) + " " + ending

print(f1("first"))
print(f2("last"))
```

first text 10

text 100 last