# Python: '{0.lower()}'.format('A') yields 'str' object has no attribute 'lower()'

Tags: python, string-formatting, attributeerror

In Python strings have a method `lower()`:

```
>>> dir('A')
[... 'ljust', 'lower', 'lstrip', ...]
```

However, when one tries `'{0.lower()}'.format('A')`, the response states:

```
>>> '{0.lower()}'.format('A')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'lower()'
```

Can someone help me understand why the line above throws an AttributeError in this case? This seems like it should not be an AttributeError, though I must be mistaken. Any help understanding this would be very welcome!

Edit: I understand I can't call the lower() method inside the format call (though it'd be neat if that were possible); my question is why doing so throws an AttributeError. This error seems misleading in this case.

Comment: You might want an f-string instead: `f'{'A'.lower()}`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't call a method from within a format specification.  Dot notation inside the format specifier is a way to look up attribute names and render their values, not to call functions.

`0.lower()` tries to look up an attribute on the string *literally* named "lower()" - the equivalent of `getattr(some_string, 'lower()')`.  You need to call the method before formatting.

```
>>> '{0.lower()}'.format('A')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'lower()'
>>> '{0}'.format('A'.lower())
'a'
```

Comment: Ah, this comment explains it! I'll accept this answer as soon as SO will let me...

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, you can't do this in a format expression. It would work in an f-string though:

```
a = "A"
print(f"{a.lower()}")
```

Comment: However unlike `str.format`, python `f-string` does not support deferred evaluation ... as seen in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42497625/how-to-postpone-defer-the-evaluation-of-f-strings