# format() on a string with a math expression inside brackets in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, format, f-string

Is there a way to get the same result using .format()?

```
a = 10
print(f'something {a+2}')
something 12
```

When I try to do it like this I get KeyError:

```
print('something {a+2}'.format(a=10))
KeyError                                  
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-94-69f36f3c6aec> in <module>
----> 1 'something {a+2}'.format(a=10)

KeyError: 'a+2'
```

Comment: `print('something {a}'.format(a=10+2)`, just do the operation outside

Comment: like this? `print('something {}'.format(a+2))` It seems like you have something specific in mind.

Comment: Netwave, none of your 8 edits (and deleted answers) have worked so far...

Comment: @NicolasGervais, yeah, I did not read the question properly.

Comment: If you added one more parenthesis, your comment above would work, however.

Comment: f-strings work differently than format. With an f-string you can do it as the first example but with format you need to do something like the examples in the comments above.

Comment: @Netwave  Yeah, I know that will work, but I'd need to rewrite a bunch of code to be able to do that. So I hoped there's a way not to do that

Comment: I would also encourage you to use f-strings whenever possible :)

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.8 new feature (Walrus)

```
a = 10
print(f'something {(result:=a+2)}')
```

Python 3.7

```
print(f'something {(a+2)}')
print(f'something {a + 2}')
print('something {a}'.format(a=10 + 2))
print('something {}'.format(a+2))
```

Updated all above options (Just to match OP's expectations)

Comment: The OP was asking more about `format` and less about f-strings. `f"{a+2}"` works with f-strings. Though using walrus for 3.8 the example is an interesting idea.

Comment: Uh! I missed that

Answer (score 0):

You may consider this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53671539/4563935

This works for your example:

```
def fstr(template):
    return eval(f"f'{template}'")

a = 10
template = "something {a + 2}"
print(fstr(template))
# Output: something 12
```