# How to print variables in python using json

Tags: python, json

So I'm having trouble printing some variable specified in a json file.
Take a  look at the code below and you'll understand.

"example.json"

```
{
    "to-print":{
        "content":"My name is {name}"
    }
}
```

"example.py"

```
import json
name = "wraithM17"
with open("example.json","r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    content = data["to-print"]["content"]
    print(f"{content}")
```

So any way I can print that variable "name" like this ?

Comment: You want to edit the json file dynamically?

Comment: No. He wants `content` to be interpreted as an `f-string`.

Comment: @wraithM17, I guess you can take a look at [How to postpone/defer the evaluation of f-strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42497625/how-to-postpone-defer-the-evaluation-of-f-strings).

Comment: you can still uses old `format()` - `print(content.format(name=name)) `

Comment: Yeah so I already found the answer and forgot to check this question. So basically its 
"example.json"
```
{
    "to-print":{
        "content":"My name is {}"
    }
}
```
then python code to print is
` print(content.format(name))