# Is it possible to do lazy formatting of a python string?

Tags: python-3.x, string, string-formatting, formatted-text, formatted-input

Instead of creating a normal formatted string:

> ```
> s = f"{1+1}" # Which would be "2"
> ```

I am receiving a variable with the string `"{1+1}"` and I need to calculate the expressions inside curly braces to end up with the literal value `"2"` on the python script.

Does Python have any built-in logic to perform this operation?

Comment: Are you sure you're running Python 3? Works for me:
```
>>> s = f"{1+1}"
>>> s
>>> 2
```

Comment: That's not what I mean. The first code works for me too.

Comment: Maybe related: [How to postpone/defer the evaluation of f-strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42497625/how-to-postpone-defer-the-evaluation-of-f-strings)

Comment: I want to compute the string "2" from a literal string "{1+1}" which comes from a 3rd party of the python code, so i cant use the normal formatted string f"".

Comment: The linked dupe or `eval`

Comment: Thanks guys, I think your material will put me in the right direction to research this.