# Using f-strings to format class attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

I have this class defined:

```
class Endpoint:
   recent_releases = "apps/{owner_name}/{app_name}/recent_releases"
   recent_latest = "apps/{owner_name}/{app_name}/releases/{release_id}"
```

and currently using `format()` to format it:

```
url = Endpoint.recent_releases.format(owner_name=owner_name, app_name=app_name)
```

Is it possible to format this using f-strings? I have tried this:

```
  class Endpoint:
      recent_releases = f"apps/{owner_name}/{app_name}/recent_releases"
      recent_latest = f"apps/{owner_name}/{app_name}/releases/{release_id}"
```

but I'd have create an `__init__()` function in the class.

Comment: No, you can't defer evaluation of `f`-strings, except by doing what you're already doing and using regular strings.

Comment: If your use case is the one I thinking on. Using computed properties would be a better choice.

Since I imagine that you would like to get different owner_name and app_name for each Enpoint instance

Comment: I should have looked further and found this after posting my question -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42497625/how-to-postpone-defer-the-evaluation-of-f-strings . I guess I'll be sticking to `.format()` for now.